# mysql query where second words starts with a letter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with:

Name Surname and Outputname ( = Name Surname )

Name and Surname should always have a value, but some time are empty.
I need to select from table by surname and i can't use surname field.
I can't even change field values with a script because i get this table from an outside source and can be change any time.
Database is MySQL 4.x

Can i select by second word in Outputname starting with some letter?
something like

```
SELECT Outputname FROM USERS 
WHERE seconword(Outputname) LIKE 'A%' SORT BY seconword(Outputname) ASC
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense to me:
" Name and Surname should always have a value, but some time are empty. " 

If they should always have a value, they will not be empty, will they?

Comment: @CompuChip :) nice catch . no one can understand it :) . contraditcion

Comment: What exactly is stored in Outputname if Surname is empty?

Comment: Ahh, looking at the accepted answer I understand the question. This is one way to work around your issue, but I would strongly recommend you try fixing the underlying problem by making the Name and Surname fields non-null and splitting the Outputname when you create or update a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(Outputname, ' ', -1) as SecondWord
   FROM USERS 
   WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Outputname, ' ', -1) LIKE 'A%'
   ORDER BY SecondWord ASC
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/051fb/1)

Comment: er, I think he wants this sorted by the surname.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
    SELECT Surname 
      FROM (
       SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Outputname, ' ', -1) 
              AS Surname
         FROM Users) AS S
    WHERE Surname LIKE 'A%' 
 ORDER BY Surname;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1d7b/1). This method is based on assumption that Outputname's format is always `'FirstName LastName'` (i.e., `' '` symbol is used as a delimiter, and used only once each time).

Comment: DB is on MySQL 4 so i flagged as correct the other answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question at all. So you only have access to Outputname (composed by two words name+surname) and you have to sort it by the second word right?

Try something like (it worked for me):

```
SELECT 
    Outputname, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Outputname, ' ', -1) as SecondWord
FROM USERS 
ORDER BY SecondWord ASC
```

Clause `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Outputname, ' ', -1) as SecondWord` returns the last word placed after a space. So If you have Outputname = 'Maria Callas' it returns 'Callas', if you have Outputname = 'Sophia Cecilia Kalos' it returns 'Kalos'.